# Magento1.9 updated orders list programatically

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

programatically fetch the magento updated orders list in magento1.9

Thanks

Comment: Which orders you want? All orders?

Comment: Yes i want all orders using date

Comment: You mean withing date range. Right?

Comment: Yes @sukumar do you have any idea

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
$fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($fromDate)); //From date
$toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($toDate)); // To date


$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection(); // All Order collection
$orders->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate)); // Filter by date range
```

**Updated Code:**

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);


$fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2018-05-01')); //From date
$toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2018-05-31')); // To date


$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection(); // All Order collection
$orders->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate)); // Filter by date range
if(count($orders) > 0){
    foreach($orders as $order){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($order->getData());
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
?>
```

I have created one file in the root magento called getorders.php and place the above code. Run it and it works fine.

Comment: $fromDate='2018-08-17 02:03:29';
$tomDate='2018-06-30 19:29:18';

$fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($fromDate)); //From date
$toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($toDate)); // To date

Comment: iam passing like above comment

Comment: iam not getting the reslut

Comment: Can you check the created_at field in database? If the format is same or not?

Comment: can you please tell me in which table i have to check

Comment: sales_flat_order

Comment: it is same as created_at

Comment: can u please send me the total code i wants try it magento root folder

Comment: Wait. I am updating my answer with whole code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82063/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-shivashankar-m).

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Is there any api like to get all updated orders by using from and to date

Comment: You can check the 2 links: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/Orders/sales_orders.html and https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/salesOrder.html which are magento's default APIs but they don't have date range option. You need to customize those according to your requirement.

Comment: Hi @sukumar iam getting lot of orders if pass (updated_at) by using from and to date.

Comment: is there any method to get updated orders